# Mixed JWT and windows authentication. Credentials popup after jwt failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, jwt, windows-authentication

I want to use JWT and Windows authentication on IIS.
On IIS I enabled Windows and Anonymous authorization.
I configured custom jwt auth:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddScheme<BearerAuthenticationSchemeOptions, BearerAuthenticationHandler>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, null);
```

```
public class BearerAuthenticationHandler
    : AuthenticationHandler<BearerAuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    private IJwtUtils _jwtUtils;
    public BearerAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<BearerAuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock,
        IJwtUtils jwtUtils)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        _jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        //if (HasAnonymousAttribute())
        //{
        //    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());
        //}

        var token = Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
        var user = _jwtUtils.ValidateJwtToken(token);

        if (user != null)
        {
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(user, this.Scheme.Name);
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }


        return AuthenticateResult.NoResult(); 
    }
}
```

I marked the method in the controller with the attribute:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

And I added auth and autorization middlewares:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

But after I returned `AuthenticateResult.NoResult()` the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method is called again. And after that pop up Windows authorization.
I was expecting the 401 code to just come back.

Why is Windows authorization called after JWT?
How do I get a 401 after the JWT authorization fails?

Comment: Are you sure that you should be returning `NoResult()`? It seems to me that you should be failing the request instead

Comment: Yes. I think Fail should be if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1853), you could find the PG has replied:

> This may not be possible in IIS. IIS will add Windows Auth challenges
> to any response with a 401 status code, triggering the login prompt.
> This happens outside of ASP.NET and your application, you don't have
> much control at that point.It should work with HttpSysServer because it's all controlled in process.

So you should not return 401 when the jwt failed. You should return other status codes and it will not trigger the login prompt like 600.